# how to get year month day from long date?

Tags: java, android

how can i extract year month and day from long date with "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

```
    long date = a.creationDate;

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatNew = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = dateFormatNew.format(date);
```

Comment: exactly the way it is posted (despite old API), assuming `a.creationDate` is milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC (like returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()`)

Comment: Do not use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore. Use the modern `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: It is always beneficial to show what you have tried

Comment: Do you know [`java.time`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)?

Comment: my code have no problem. i wat to get year for yyyy. just this

Comment: use `"yyyy"` instead of `"dd/MM/yyyy"` !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the single values of year, month and day of month from a datetime given in milliseconds, you should nowadays use `java.time` for that.
See this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example millis of "now"
    long millis = Instant.now().toEpochMilli(); // use your a.creationDate; here instead
    // create an Instant from the given milliseconds
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
    // create a LocalDateTime from the Instant using the time zone of your system
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    // then print the single parts of that LocalDateTime
    System.out.println("Year: " + ldt.getYear()
        + ", Month: " + ldt.getMonthValue()
        + " (" + ldt.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)
        + "), Day: " + ldt.getDayOfMonth()
        + " (" + ldt.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)
        + ")");
}
```

The output is this:

```
Year: 2020, Month: 3 (March), Day: 6 (Friday)
```

If you are supporting Android API levels below 26, you will, unfortunately, have to import a [backport library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) for instructions...

Comment: thanks it work. but can you help for lower api. this work for 26 and higher

Comment: @Mohammadkhorsand yes, see my edited answer.